# Jasmine - Testing/Spying on a Subject in an Angular component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, observable

My component has a `Subject<void>`, which when emits, calls another function - `refresh()`. In my unit tests, I need to test this behavior, or more specifically, that the `refresh()` function is called.

Based on the Jasmine docs on [Spying on properties](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/spying_on_properties), I tried to use `spyOnProperty()`, but it always throws me an error - `Error: <spyOnProperty> : Property filterEvent does not have access type get`

Component -

```js
filterEvent = new Subject<void>();
```

Test -

```js
 fit('refresh on filter events', fakeAsync(() => {
    const filterSub = new Subject<void>();
    const filterEventSpy = spyOnProperty<any>(component, 'filterEvent', 'get').and.returnValue(filterSub);
    spyOn(component, 'refresh');
    filterSub.next();
    tick(500);
    expect(component.refresh).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

Error -

```
    Error: <spyOnProperty> : Property filterEvent does not have access type get
Usage: spyOnProperty(<object>, <propName>, [accessType])
Error: <spyOnProperty> : Property filterEvent does not have access type get
Usage: spyOnProperty(<object>, <propName>, [accessType])
    at <Jasmine>
```

Comment: what is the point of your test?

Comment: @ManishGiri where is the function that is to be tested? currently test case is written incorrectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
it('refresh on filter events', fakeAsync(() => {
   const filterSub = new Subject<void>();
   const filterEventSpy = spyOn<any>(component, 'filterEvent').and.returnValue(filterSub);
   spyOn(component, 'refresh');
   filterSub.next();
   tick(500);
   expect(component.refresh).toHaveBeenCalled();
 }));
```